# How to get List of Images Using NSBundle

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am having List of images in my project i have to get the entire list Using NSBundle, How can i do this

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 NSLog(@"Images in bundle are:");

 NSString *imageExtension = @"png";
 NSArray *pngPaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:imageExtension inDirectory:nil];
 for (NSString *filePath in pngPaths)
 {
     NSString *fileName = [filePath lastPathComponent];
     NSLog(@"%@", fileName);
 }
```

Just change the `imageExtension` string for the image type you want.